# why is subprocess.checkoutput returning an extra new line?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

```
import subprocess
output = str(subprocess.check_output(['lspci','-n']),'utf-8')
print(output)
```

the output is returned with a extra new line why ?

[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) always adds a newline.

> print(*objects, sep=' ', **end='\n'**, file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

This can be supressed:

```
print(output, end='')
```